# Why the last digits displayed in a DoubleUpDown/SingleUpDown changed randomly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed, numericupdown

Code First:

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
...

<xctk:SingleUpDown Value="{Binding floatvalue}" FormatString="F7" Minimum="0"/>
...
```

**floatvalue** is a property of **float** Type.

If the user type "8.76543212" in the **SingleUpDown** and then leave focus (**Press Tab**), the value will change to 8.7654320 (frequently) or 8.7654300 (seldom).

But if comment the {Binding } out,

```
<xctk:SingleUpDown Value="0.1234567" FormatString="F7" Minimum="0"/>
```

All works well.

In conclusion, there are two requirements to reproduce this issue：
1. Bind Value to a property;
2. Change focus after modifying.

I've added a customized Converter to capture the value before and after change, no help.

I've also tried to dig into the source code of [NumericUpDown](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Implementation/CommonNumericUpDown.cs) but I can not find any useful informations.

The behind C# code is simple:

```
public float floatvalue { get; set; }
```

The last digits of NumericUpDown should display precisely.

Comment: Take a look at [Floating-point types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/floating-point-types-table). `float` has a precision of only 6-9 digits. Use `double` instead.

Comment: You're right! Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's the problem with IEEE 754 - it's not super precise. Try using `decimal` instead - it's a 128 bit datatype that will not round.

Compared to other floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations - 
[decimal (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

Comment: Finally solved by changing the floatvalue to a double property and replacing xctk:SingleUpDown with xctk:DoubleUpDown